# Internet Working in android using Local DNS

Tags: android, security, proxy, dns, wireshark

I changed the DNS1 AND DNS2 address of my android phone in my home WiFi with the ip address of my laptop which is in the same network. I cleared all the dns caches in my phone.
After this, When I go to a site I thought the site won't load since the laptop doesn't know how to respond to the dns request of my. Phone.
But the Internet is working fine and even newer sites are loading.
When I use Wireshark in my laptop it shows me the DNS request and ICMP response between my phone and the laptop. 
How is it possible?  am I missing anything?